# Can I freeze/remove com.android.keyguard if I don't use the lockscreen?

Tags: lock-screens, optimization

What is exactly com.android.keyguard?
Is it just handling the lockscreen?
If I set my device not to lock when screen is turned off, can I safely freeze/remove com.android.keyguard?

I'm using a galaxy nexus with cyanogenmod 11 (kitkat), trying to lower RAM usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`com.android.keyguard` runs your lockscreen, home button, and a few other things I can't remember.

It's an integral part of Android.  Don't remove it.

Comment: ok I totally don't wanna loose the home button

Answer (score 2):

If you disable/freeze com.android.keyguard, your device's Home button will stop working until you enable/unfreeze it.
This process keeps running all the time, but it is not a Battery drainer so don't worry and don't disable it.